# Logrotate without root user access not working

Tags: logrotate

The problem is that we don't have EASY root access to servers. That's why being able to run logrotate without being root is very handy. This is what I did after following articles on the internet.

1. Create a directory  /home/techyman/logrotate with two files logrotate.conf and logrotate.status
2. Put your logrotate configuration files there in logrotate.conf

```
/home/techyman/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/*/logs/*.log {
        su techyman techyman
        daily
        copytruncate
        missingok
        rotate 30
        compress
        notifempty
        dateext dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
}
```

3. Run a cron job

```
0 1 * * *  /usr/sbin/logrotate -s /home/techyman/logrotate/logrotate.status /home/techyman/logrotate/logrotate.conf
```

This runs everyday at 1 AM.
To test every 1 second, just do `* * * * *` in cron job.
But it's not working. When I force it, it says "bad line at top in status file", otherwise no actions are being seen. I just see application.log alone.

How do I fix this issue? What am I doing wrong?

I removed `notifempty` and still it's not working.

I then removed `su techyman techyman` and still it's not working.

Finally manually doing this works. But the cron job still doesn't work.

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /home/techyman/logrotate/logrotate.status  
 -f /home/techyman/logrotate/logrotate.conf
```

Output of `head -5 logrotate.status`

```
logrotate state -- version 2
"/home/techyman/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/b/logs/application.log" 2023-11-19-17:46:26
"/home/techyman/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/application.log" 2023-11-19-17:46:26
"/home/techyman/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/e/logs/application.log" 2023-11-19-17:46:26
"/home/techyman/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/c/logs/application.log" 2023-11-19-17:46:26
```

I removed `daily` from logrotate.conf hoping it would fix the issue but it still doesn't work from cron.

Comment: Please run `head -5 /home/techyman/logrotate/logrotate.status`. What is the output? (Please edit your question, don't write it as a comment.)

Comment: Eyeballing the question, there is a difference between the manual command at the end and the command in the crontab: `-f` is missing in the latter. It may be a typo, it may or may not be the problem, but you should fix it anyway.

Comment: The thing is I'm running the cron with `* * * * *` that is every second, so every second (even without `-f` it should do the log rotation)

Comment: @telcoM did it.

Comment: Unless you have a non-standard `cron`, a cron job specified as `* * * * *` is every **minute**, not every second. (it's "each minute of each hour of each day of each month, and every weekday)

Comment: Yes every minute. But it's not working every minute either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message `bad top line in state file` indicates that the *state* file (the one you specified with the `-s` option) does exist, but its first line is not either

```
logrotate state -- version 1
```

or

```
logrotate state -- version 2
```

If you created the file yourself (e.g. with `touch /home/techyman/logrotate/logrotate.status`), then this error is expected. If the file does not exist, `logrotate` will automatically create it on the first run if the directory permissions allow it, and will add the proper header line automatically. After running `logrotate` once with the `-f` option, it may have fixed it automatically.

Because `logrotate` updates the state file by first creating a new file and then renaming it to the old state file, the directory permissions must allow `logrotate` to create files to the state file directory, or else updating the state file won't work at all.

Also note this on `logrotate(8)` man page:

> Normally, `logrotate` is run as a daily cron job. **It will not modify a
> log more than once in one day** unless the criterion for that log is based on the log's size and logrotate is being run more than once each day, or unless the -f or --force option is used.

In your `logrotate.conf`, the option `daily` specifies that the logs are to be rotated once per day only. If you change it to `hourly`, you can get the logs rotated once per hour, but running `logrotate` more than once per hour will still be useless.

If you want the logs rotated more ofthen than once per hour, you must remove all time interval options and specify a `size` option instead.

Also, running `logrotate` every minute, especially with the `compress` option enabled, makes it likely that the previous `logrotate` job has not yet finished when the next one is trying to start. `logrotate` attempts to lock the state file when it starts, in order to prevent this from happening.